# What is the modern way to do small scale programmable logic?

Tags: digital-logic, programmable-logic

I am designing a circuit for an electronic coil winder. It has a few binary counters, equality detectors, 7 segment decoders and flip flops.

How it is possible to get all of this logic onto 1 programmable chip without resorting to totally retro technology?

Is there something like a GAL that can is well supported for programming on a modern computer?

I can easily make it from standard CMOS or TTL chips, but it would be a good learning opportunity to try programming my own logic.

Comment: Why would you want to even implement that with logic ? Do you need a very high speed ? I don't think so. Why not simply use a microcontroller. Then you **program** the behavior you need. Sure it sounds silly to use a software solution to make a simple logic function. But it is easier and more flexible.

Comment: I am already familiar with building logic circuits, and I would like to learn how to do it because I may be able to use those skills to do other projects. I am more comfortable with hard wired circuit design than I am with sequential programming. I can see why other people would use a microcontroller.

Comment: CPLD is the acronym for 'small' FPGAs, custom programmable logic device. Lattice as mentioned in the answer below is probably the best source to start looking at these. But really, PIC or Arduino would be the place that 999/1000 engineers (possible under estimate here) would start for your specific (very low speed) application.

Comment: Hi there @Neil_UK, interesting your '999/1000' engineers would use an MCU - I've seen the total opposite :-) Few people in the companies I've been in choose an MCU for a logic job, nor more than they'd use an op-amp as a voltage regulator...it's possible but the wrong tool. I've used both some I'm very agnostic. It sounds like it's just your personal experience, though I imagine you've not worked with several thousand engineers :-) , and I can only speaking from mine, obviously. For price, support but more simplicity and failure mode, seems crazy to me and I understand the counter-arguments.

Comment: @TonyM 999/1000 was intended to be provocative, and of course it's a figure PDOOMA. I think my comment was swayed my last most recent employer where we sprinkled Arduinos around like Smarties for custom test gear, though the product itself used a micropower TI MCU/radio. Whenever we talked about a homer that we were doing, it was usually Arduino based.

Comment: @Neil_UK, it did provoke a reaction...but slightly more of "Poor, poor boy" than "Wow, this freaky far-out dude beats all us squares down a mineshaft" :-D I actually would love to work on projects where the fun solution you'd do at home isn't the polar opposite of the 'proper engineering solution' but they don't come along that often. Test equipment usually lets the brakes off a bit. I actually don't mind what we go for, so long as it falls out of the requirements and isn't someone's favourite way that turns out to be the only way they know. Have a chilled weekend, chief :-)

Comment: @TonyM What do you think about the various visual schematic FPGA programming options? Like Altera's Quartus or Xilinx's ISE or Simulink for Matlab.

Comment: @NickCollier, as others have said, Quartus and ISE have several design inputs: schematic, AHDL, VHDL, Verilog and C. Briefly: schematic's too limiting and drags you into how it's done, not just what you want; AHDL's ancient crud; C's only there to use transformation algorithms quickly; VHDL's brilliant; dunno much Verilog. Simulink offer VHDL into FPGAs as speed increase over PC sim' or rare don't-care situations, not for day-to-day input (worked project with 4 other engineers who tried just that - failed badly). Done loads of VHDL into Quartus/ISE, go for it Nick you'll be glad, great on CV.

Comment: @TonyM I watched a video on VHDL structural programming. It seems like if you have described a simple logic circuit, which then gets 'put in a box' and then later repeated, you need to rewrite the statement for the logic circuit every time it is used. I would expect that you could just refer to the name of the box without having to rewrite it's contents.

Comment: No, that'd be crazy. VHDL is very structured, allows good abstraction and reuse. But I can't tutor you on it in a comment conversation. Wade into a VHDL tutorial, there's plenty around. If you want a starter, go to chat (if you can, I will if you can't) with me and we can go further.

Comment: @TonyM  Maybe I watched the wrong video. I will try and learn it myself as much as possible. I did know know it was possible to chat or sent private messages on SE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The modern way to do such a digital logic circuit would be in an FPGA or CPLD.

The way I'd recommend for your particular logic circuit is a CPLD. Have a look at the Altera MAX10 family or the Lattic iCE40 devices. You can buy a cheap demo' board like the iCEStick, download the free development tools and get something up to experiment with at home or work.

You will have to learn VHDL (my preference) or Verilog but that's part of the learning you mentioned you're interested in doing.

You could use a microcontroller to produce a similar result but by a quite different function...but it doesn't address your question. And you'd have to learn to programme that so there's work either way.

(I know Lattice call iCE40 an FPGA family, but across the logic chips market, they have more in common with CPLDs. The name will do for the purpose here.)

Comment: Just a quick comment: ice40 was maybe ten years ago. Bow lattice mainstream is MachXO2, which is my preference, actually for that stuff. Altera's Max10 would also have internal ADC, but quartus somehow became less friendly than diamond...

Comment: Hi @GregoryKornblum, thanks for the comment. In advocating these devices I went on popularity and sales costs from the distributors. Always found Quartus the most newcomer-friendly of all of them. Good recommendation for the MachX02.

Comment: I happen to use both. Frankly, you can tell Altera doesn't consider MAX10 very important. MachXO2 performs much better.

Answer (score 3):

Microcontrollers are the modern way, but if you have reasons to avoid them (safety, or you don't know C), you need to use low cost FPGA, from either altera (now intel), xilinx, lattice or microsemi.

Comment: So are there any small FPGAs with less than 1000 gates?

Comment: I doubt it. They count LUTs, which is equivalent of maybe 10-20 gates, so smallest have several hundreds of them. Byt they only cost a little more than microcontrollers

Comment: By the way. Although there is usually a way to actually design FPGA gate by gate, it's absolutely not recommended. Normally people use VHDL or (the sick people among us) verilog. This is way more efficient for designs larger than 10-20 gates

Comment: I notice that Xilinx and Altera offer visual schematic programming options. Xilinx has ISE and Altera has Quartus. They look more easy than to use than a text based environment.

Comment: Maybe for a start. If you are serious about using fpga- very soon you will need VHDL.

Comment: Ok, so what are the limitations of these visual programming environments? I imagine that in some cases a text based object is identical to symbol in a schematic.

Comment: Both visual and text represent same things. But with text you have some level of abstraction, like conditioning that is compiled to multiplexers and other stuff, while in visual design go draw all that.

Comment: ISE and Quartus offer many different programming options, so I can see which is best.

Comment: I am afraid, learning all of those is too much of effort. Again, for short term go with what is easy and natural for you, for longer term- VHDL or verilog.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, a new device has just come to market:

https://www.dialog-semiconductor.com/products/greenpak

It is the GreenPack series from Dialog semiconductor. You can implement most of the logic from discrete chips inside them, include custom LUTs, some of them also incorporate ADCs so you can perform analog functions, etc.

They are available from distributors pretty cheap, about 0.42€@100:

https://www.mouser.es/ProductDetail/Dialog-Semiconductor/SLG46620G?qs=%252B6g0mu59x7KnBmBQ6c05jQ%3D%3D

Hope you find this useful.

Comment: Renesas (nee Silego, nee Dialog) Greenpak has been around for a while, at least since 2010. I've used them in several products.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to TonyM's answer:

If you just want some programmable logic and don't want a sequential processor (a micro controller), here's a tiny iCE40 chip:

http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Lattice/ICE40UL1K-SWG16ITR50/?qs=XJu%252bLGjWfSDdbhkO3WpKug%3D%3D

There are also parts like this that give you little logic blocks to work with:
http://www.ti.com/product/cd4048b